# QR Code to open local PDF files

Tags: pdf, qr-code

I want to create a QR code specifically using the "Barcode Generator" app.  I would like to have it automatically open a local pdf or doc.  The concept would be to have 10-15 QR codes that would open 1 of many docs I have on my tablet.  What code or text can be used to achieve this?

Comment: The file command will open pdfs and only in Adobe. Is there another command that opens documents in other programs or gives the option of what program to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can be accomplished at all in a cross-platform standard way, it will be by encoding a URL like `file:///path/to/doc1.pdf` in a QR code. It's not guaranteed that the platform will honor this URL and open the file, but, it might.

Comment: Sean, That worked.  The file command will open pdfs and only in Adobe.  Is there another command that opens documents in other programs or gives the option of what program to use?  Thank you so much for your help!